# Mapping over a const variable and returning to the value of an input

Tags: json, reactjs, object

I've been building a multi-step form flow in React/Gatsby, and right now i'm mapping over the form fields like so.

```
{clientContactDetailsData.map((item, idx) => (
    <>
        <Form.Label className="d-block text-left mb-0">{item.name}</Form.Label>
        <Form.Control
            type="text"
            name={item.name}
            className="selectButtons"
            onChange={handleChange(item.value)}
            defaultValue={values}
        />
    </>
))}
```

`name` and `value` come from a JSON object that i'm exporting. `name: 'Full Name'`, `value: 'fullName'`

For `defaultValue`, I'm passing a `values` variable through props. It's built as an object for all of the different fields:

```
const values = { clientType, clientGoal, clientDetails, contactPreference, fullName, companyName, email, phoneNumber };
```

The fields I'm using for `clientContactDetailsData` are only `fullName, companyName, email, phoneNumber`, so my goal is to map over only these, and pass them to the `defaultValue` property, so that when I show a confirmation of the details, the values that the user entered will show. `Full Name: John`

Comment: JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More here.)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON.

Comment: Is the question how to pick out the correct value from `values` for each `defaultValue` prop for the `Form.Control`? If so, the answer is [`defaultValue={values[item.name]}`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thank you! that was it